# How to set target (runlevel) to service in CentOS7 (Systemd)?

Tags: centos, target, systemd, runlevel

I want to set target to service in CentOS7 (Systemd).
I want to know following.

- How to set target to service.
- How to show target of service.

In other words, I want to know substitution for following commands.

```
$ sudo chkconfig --level=2345 mysql on (<- set runlevel)
$ chkconfig --list mysql (<- show runlevel)
```

---

I understood that "runlevel" in CentOS6 changed "target" in CentOS7and I should use "systemctl" command.

But problems were not solved.

I heard that following command is replacement for "chkconfig --list"
, but I can't check target and can't set target.

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions about systemd are better suited to http://serverfault.com or unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemd Questions on SO are expected to be directly about programming.

Comment: Mark Stosberg Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the target is done in the unit file for the service. For example:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then you run `systemctl enable $service_name` to create a symlink which enables the service to start as part of a particular target. You could also create the symlinks manually. The `enable` command will print out the paths of the symlinks it's creating.

I think `systemctl  --reverse  list-dependencies $service` is the way to find what services and targets depend on a specific services to boot.